# regular expression to match a pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regular expression for c# which can match following pattern

> **abc1abcd**
>   **1abcdefg** 
>   **abcdefg1**

basically my expression should have at least one number and min size is 8 char including number. **If possible explain the regex also.**

Comment: I suggest its better to sort them and compare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression pattern should just be: `\d+` (match 1 or more numbers). For your example, it's probably best to not determine minimum length using regex since all you care about is that it has at least 1 number and is at least than 8 characters

```
Regex regEx = new Regex(@"\d+");
isValid = regEx.Match(myString).Success && myString.Length >= 8;
```

The pattern `\d` is just the same as `[0-9]` and the `+` symbol means `at least one of`. The `@` symbol in front of the string is so that it what try to escape `\d`.

As mentioned by El Ronnoco in the comments, just `\d` would match your requirement. Knowing about `\d+` is useful for more complicated patterns where you want a few numbers in between some strings,etc.

**Also**: I've just read something that I didn't know. `\d` matches any character in the [Unicode number, decimal digit](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm) category which is a lot more than just `[0-9]`. Something to be aware of if you just want any number. Otherwise El Ronnoco's answer of `[0-9]` for your pattern is sufficient.

Comment: +1 Good explanation. Although I think just `"\d"` will suffice for the OP's requirements?

Comment: Thanks - I've updated my answer and also added a bit that I didn't realise about `\d` matching all unicode numbers

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably check with two statements. Just check the length eg

```
string.Length > 7
```

and then make sure it this regex can find a match...

```
[0-9]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [look-ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to verify the length, and then search forward for a digit, thus:

```
(?=.{8}).*[0-9]
```

We look-ahead for 8 characters, and if that is successful, then we actually attempt to match "anything, followed by a digit".

But really, don't do this. Just check the length explicitly. It's much clearer.

Comment: +1 For the alternative idea of using the look ahead (although I agree that checking the length explicitly is much clearer).

Comment: +1 Clever. I didn't really know you could use lookahead like that, but I suppose it makes sense.

Comment: Regexes are supposed to be for lateral thinkers, right? That's why you end up with two problems when you think you'll use one to solve the first problem. ;)